# Generate Dates in oracle with gaps during Time Period

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, oracle11g, oracle10g

I Need To Generate Dates During Specific Time Period ( Using Oracle SQL Developer 12& 18).
/
I Found Bellow Solution:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('01/01/2020','DD/MM/YYYY') + (ROWNUM - 1) DATEGEN
FROM ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE TO_DATE('01/01/2020','DD/MM/YYYY') + (ROWNUM -1) <=  TO_DATE('01/11/2020','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

I Get Daily Dates (As Bellow):

```
01-JAN-20 12.00.00 AM 
02-JAN-20 12.00.00 AM 
03-JAN-20 12.00.00 AM 
04-JAN-20 12.00.00 AM 
05-JAN-20 12.00.00 AM 
06-JAN-20 12.00.00 AM
```

I Need To Get Dates With Gap 5 days or 3 days (Example):

```
01-JAN-20 12.00.00 AM

05-JAN-20 12.00.00 AM

10-JAN-20 12.00.00 AM

15-JAN-20 12.00.00 AM
```

Any Suggestions?!
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why is the first gap 4 days?

Comment: by Mistake!!,, It Must Be 31 - Dec - 19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the hiearchy query with simple logic as follows:

```
SELECT DATE '2020-01-01' + ( LEVEL * 5 ) - 1
  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY
    LEVEL <= ( DATE '2020-11-01' - DATE '2020-01-01' ) / 5;
```

Please note that in your question first two dates have 4 days of difference and in my solution, the First date will be 05-01-2020

Comment: Grate!.. ThanQ U

Answer (score 2):

You could use a standad recursive query:

```
with cte (dt) as (
    select date '2020-01-01' from dual
    union all
    select dt + interval '5' day from cte where dt < date '2020-01-15'
)
select * from cte order by dt
```

You can adjust the boundaries as needed, or move them to another cte:

```
with 
    params (startdt, enddt) as (
        select date '2020-01-01', date '2020-01-15' from dual
    ),
    cte (dt, enddt) as (
        select startdt dt, enddt from params
        union all
        select dt + interval '5' day, enddt from cte where dt < enddt
    )
select dt from cte order by dt
```

Note that the intervals between the dates are not constant in your sample data (there are 4 days between the first two dates, then 5 days.

You might want to adjust the `where` clause of the recursive member depending on your actual requirement. Here, the last day may be greater the January 15th. If you don't want that, then change the `where` clause to:

```
where dt + interval '5' day < enddt
```

Comment: Genus Solution!.. ThanQ You.. I were no Idea About Using With!